# Magento 2; joinLeft() not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, join

I have this code to join status to the `order` item collection:

```
    $orderItems = $this->orderItemCollection->addFieldToSelect(
        array('item_id','order_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at','product_id','sku','name')
    );

    $orderItems->getSelect()->join('sales_order','order_id = entity_id','status');

    $data = $orderItems->getData();
```

It works fine but I want to make sure all order items are returned regardless of whether or not there is a status so I tried:

```
    $orderItems = $this->orderItemCollection->addFieldToSelect(
        array('item_id','order_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at','product_id','sku','name')
    );

    $orderItems->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_order','order_id = entity_id','status');

    $data = $orderItems->getData();
```

This doesn't work for some reason.  In my `debugger` after that line is hit `execution` just `stops` and a `white page` is returned.

Is there a different way I should be doing left join?

edit:

The last method that is called before execution stops is `\vendor\magento\framework\App\ErrorHandler.php` `handler()` method.
Seems like something happens that stops it reporting the error

Comment: Uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in app/bootstrap.php to see what the error message is.

Comment: its already uncommented.  I usually see errors but joinLeft just breaks execution and leaves nothing in apache log or exception log

Comment: If I break line before the getdata call the debugger seems to break it for some reason.  If I remove my breakpoint then it works, seems to be some conflict with xdebug

Comment: use  echo $orderItems->getSelect(); and print the query and hit it directly in DB to check its output.. 
you will surely find something helpful